# how to bind y and x coordinates to an image in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I want to move the image with mouse click. I have already set up `x` and `y` mouse movement, but I don't know how to bind these coordinates to the image.

Can anyone help me? I am using `VUE.JS`

Comment: Can you share your current code, especially the part that you position the image in your html document?

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to [bind an inline style](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles) that sets the absolute position of the `<img>`:

1. Create an `<img>` tag:

   ```
   <img class="my-img">
   ```
2. Style it so it's absolutely positioned:

   ```
   .my-img {
     position: absolute;
   }
   ```
3. Bind its `style` to an object that sets the [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) (Y-coordinate) and [`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) (X-coordinate). In the following example, we bind `top` to a data field named `imgTop` and `left` to one named `imgLeft`. When our component sets `imgTop`, the `<img>`'s `top` will be set to the same value; and similarly for `left` and `imgLeft`. *We'll add the `imgTop` and `imgLeft` data fields later.*

   ```
   <img class="my-img" :style="{ top: imgTop, left: imgLeft }">
   ```
4. Create a `<div>` to contain the `<img>`. This container will represent the clickable area, where the `<img>` can be moved.

   ```
   <div class="container">
     <img class="my-img">
   </div>
   ```
5. Style the container to be as large as the viewport (using [`vw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vw) and [`vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vh) length units):

   ```
   .container {
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
   }
   ```
6. Set a `click`-event handler on the container. We use [`v-on:EVENT=METHOD`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events) to assign a method that handles the event (there's also a shorthand syntax for this -- `@EVENT=METHOD`). *We'll add the `onClick` method later*.

   ```
   <div class="container" @click="onClick">
   ```
7. Create the `imgTop` and `imgLeft` fields in your component's `data`:

   ```
   extern default {
     data: () => ({
       imgLeft: null,
       imgTop: null,
     }),
   }
   ```
8. Create the event-handler method in your component's `methods`. Note the handler formats the [`MouseEvent.clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX) and [`MouseEvent.clientY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientY) into pixel lengths (appends `px`), and assigns the results to `imgLeft` and `imgTop`.

   ```
   extern default {
     methods: {
       onClick(e) {
         this.imgLeft = `${e.clientX}px`;
         this.imgTop = `${e.clientY}px`;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    imgLeft: null,
    imgTop: null,
  }),
  methods: {
    onClick(e) {
      this.imgLeft = `${e.clientX}px`;
      this.imgTop = `${e.clientY}px`;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="container" @click.stop="onClick">
    <img class="img"
         src="//placekitten.com/100/100"
         width="100"
         alt="kitty"
         :style="{top: imgTop, left: imgLeft}">
  </div>
</div>
```